# JQuery Or Javascript is not working after Partial PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with a GridView and Two Buttons namely- Save & Reset and some textboxes to hold values from GridView record.
If i clicked on any record in the gridview then all the column values placed in specific textboxes and Save button's text changes into "Update" and the textboxes has to become empty.
But whenever i do it,the textboxes becomes empty but the Save button's text Changes for a second and again converted to "Update".
Following is the JQuery Code embedded into pageLoad function.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnExpReset.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            try {
                $('#<%= txtCompanyName.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%= txtExpDesignation.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%= txtSalary.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%= txtExpFromDate.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%= txtExpToDate.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#<%= txtLivingReason.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);

                $('#<%= txtCompanyName.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtExpDesignation.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtSalary.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtExpFromDate.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtExpToDate.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtLivingReason.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtExpYears.ClientID %>').val("");
                $('#<%= txtExpMonths.ClientID %>').val("");

                var RB1 = document.getElementById("<%=rdbExperience.ClientID%>");
                var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");

                for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
                    if (radio[i].value == 2) {
                        radio[i].checked = true;
                    }
                }

                $('#<%= btnAddExp.ClientID %>').val("Add Experience");
                alert("Inner Clicked");

                return true;
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Please let me know of any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code? Using developer tools for your browser?

Comment: Hi Naveed.I am not aware of developer tools.Can you please tell me.

Comment: press f12 in your browser (probably best in chrome IMO), also you can chain events: `$('#<%= txtCompanyName.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true).val("")`.  Also why is your document ready within another function? If you are calling the function to bind the click event then you don't need the document redy

Comment: I would also use `Console.log` rather than `alert`, because I often forget to remove them before deploying them on server and they annoy the user...

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.